# Want to fetch data from 3 tables while summing up 1 column

Tags: mysql

```
table (user)
+----------------------+
|id | name | course_id |
|----------------------|
|01 | cena | 24        |
|02 | john | 42        |
+----------------------+

table (courses)
+---------------------------------+
|id | user_id | coursename | fee  |
|---------------------------------|
|24 | 01      | Illustrator| 4000 |
|42 | 02      | Photoshop  | 3000 |
+---------------------------------+

table (fee)
+---------------------------+
|id | user_id | paid_amount |
|---------------------------|
|01 | 01      | 400         |
|02 | 02      | 800         |
|03 | 01      | 600         |
|04 | 02      | 1200        |
+---------------------------+
```

[image]

ive tried this query but didnt worked

**$query = "SELECT A.id, A.name, C.coursename, C.fee, B.'total paid fee' FROM 'user' A**

**LEFT JOIN (SELECT user_id, SUM(paid_amount) 'total paid fee' FROM fee GROUP BY user_id) B ON A.id=B.user_id**

**LEFT JOIN courses C ON A.id=C.user_id;";**

```
<?php 
    $query = "above query";
    $query = $connect->prepare($query);
    $query->execute();
    if($query->rowCount()):
    while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo $row['id']; 
    echo $row['name']; 
    echo $row['coursename']; 
    echo $row['fee']; 
    echo $row['total paid fee']; 
    } 
    endif; 
?>
```

Comment: Getting any errors? looks like you overriding the `$query` var

Comment: php outputed html table is empty with 0 data

Comment: Try this `SELECT A.id, A.name, C.coursename, C.fee, SUM(C.paid_amount) as total_paid_fee FROM user A
LEFT JOIN  FROM fee B ON A.id=B.user_id
LEFT JOIN courses C ON A.id=C.user_id
group by A.id, A.name, C.coursename, C.fee;`

Comment: @JYoThI no working same blank output without any data

Comment: Try to Execute the query directly in mysql @DoeJohn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove single quotes around your table name like `'user'` instead you can use bacticks `, Moreover do not use spaces in aliase name like`'total paid fee'`instead you can write it as`totalPaidFee`or`total_paid_fee`

```
SELECT A.id, 
       A.name, 
       C.coursename, 
       C.fee, 
       B.total_paid_fee, 
       C.fee - B.total_paid_fee AS remaining_fee 
FROM   `user` A 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT user_id, 
                         Sum(paid_amount) total_paid_fee 
                  FROM   fee 
                  GROUP  BY user_id) B 
              ON A.id = B.user_id 
       LEFT JOIN courses C 
              ON A.id = C.user_id
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/485687/2)

Comment: asslamu alaykum khalid, ive tried ur solution but still no results in html table

Comment: error was showing because of 'user' ive removed single quote it worked perfectly .

Comment: thank you so much bro for your great help may Allah (S.W.T) bless you . :-)